# How to divide seekbar into 2 different parts and with 2 different default steps in Android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, rangeseekbar

I'm creating a custom seek-bar with 2 thumbs, and seek-bar range is 0-10000000, My question is that I want to divide that seek-bar into 2 equal parts and first part range is 0-1000000 with default steps 10000 and second part range is 1000001-10000000 with default steps 100000.

Comment: Please edit the question properly.

Comment: @Vikas Yadav i was edited as per my knowledge please my question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library over the GitHub using which you can solve your problem.Here is the link to library [here](https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar)

**Add a dependency to your build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
}
```

Answering your questions:-

1. It is a double thumb range seek bar.
2. You can set **minimum** and **maximum** range of the seek bar using attributes

   ```
   app:min_value="0" //minimum value
   app:max_value="150" // maximum value
   ```
3. You can set **step size** using following attribute

   ```
   app:steps="5"// add required step size here
   ```

Your XML code for seek bar will look like this:-

```
<com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.BubbleThumbSeekbar
    android:id="@+id/rangeSeekbar3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:corner_radius="10"
    app:min_value="0"
    app:max_value="100"
    app:steps="5"
    app:bar_color="#F7BB88"
    app:bar_highlight_color="#E07416"
    app:left_thumb_image="@drawable/thumb"
    app:left_thumb_image_pressed="@drawable/thumb_pressed"
    app:data_type="_integer"/>
```

In java class you can impement `setOnSeekbarChangeListener()` like this:-

```
final CrystalSeekbar seekbar = new CrystalSeekbar(getActivity());

// get min and max text view
final TextView tvMin = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textMin5);
final TextView tvMax = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textMax5);

// set listener
seekbar.setOnSeekbarChangeListener(new OnSeekbarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(Number minValue) {
        tvMin.setText(String.valueOf(minValue));
    }
});
```

Hope this might help!! Thanks.